# Type 'FixedScrollMetrics' is not a subtype of type 'PageMetrics'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

**I'm using a ListView inside a PageView.**

**in pubspec.yaml:**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

 cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
 page_indicator: ^0.3.0
```

**Code inside the Wigdet:**

GlobalKey _pageKey =new GlobalKey();

```
    PageIndicatorContainer(
                key: _pageKey,
               length: 2,
               indicatorSpace: 5.0,
                    shape:IndicatorShape.roundRectangleShape(
                       size: Size(50.0, 12.0), 
                    ),
                    indicatorSelectorColor: white,
                     indicatorColor: white,
                child: PageView(
                  controller: controller,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: 
                      childAppbar(),
            ),
            ListView(),
          ],

        ),
         ),
```

Answer (score 0):

a workaround is to use this extension on `FixedScrollMetrics`:

```
extension on FixedScrollMetrics {
  double get page {
    return math.max(0.0, pixels.clamp(minScrollExtent, maxScrollExtent)) /
        math.max(1.0, viewportDimension);
  }
}
```